# How do I bring the home launcher to front, but not previous activities?

Tags: android, minimize, android-launcher

How do I minimize my activity and bring the home launcher to front, but not previous activities?

I need this as I set a wallpaper from my app (which is not a live wallpaper, just a regular app) and need to bring the home launcher to front for the user to see the new wallpaper. Is it possible to do this? I tried `finish()` but it brings the previous app to front, not the home launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intent with the Action:

```
Intent.ACTION_MAIN
```

and Category:

```
Intent.CATEGORY_HOME
```

Will Suffice

Ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will allow the user to go back to home their respective home. Regardless of the launcher type (adw, launcherpro, stock, etc..). Specifically all launchers will handle this Intent Action/Category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I know this is an old post but hope will be helpful to someone in future.

```
final PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
Intent intent = null;
Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

List<Intent> targettedHomeIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo:packageManager.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))
{
    if(!getPackageName().equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))  //if this activity is not in our activity (in other words, it's another default home screen)
    {
        intent = new Intent(intentToResolve);
        //intent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

        targettedHomeIntents.add(intent);
    }
}

if(targettedHomeIntents.size() > 0){
    if(targettedHomeIntents.size() == 1) {
        startActivity(targettedHomeIntents.get(0));
    } else {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targettedHomeIntents.remove(0), "Select Home");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targettedHomeIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` into the intent flags to bring launcher to front task together with the target Activity so when you finish the target activity, Launcher will show up.